# Re run cucumber scenarios using ClueCumber report plugin

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber

I can see there is an option of retry scenarios in Extended Cucumber Options plugin , is there an similar option to re run failed scenarios having a single report which shows rerun count on it ? with respect to Cluecumber Report Plugin. Please help

https://tech.trivago.com/2017/11/16/cluecumber-report-maven-plugin-for-cucumber-test-reporting/

Answer (score 2):

Cluecumber works with JSON files generated by Cucumber. As those JSON files do not contain any indicators of retried scenarios, this is not possible.